# Can I downgrade Catalina to El Capitan using a flash drive?

Tags: restore

I downloaded Catalina but it broke critical applications on my computer, I need to restore it to El Capitan as it was before, can I do it safely with a bootable USB?

Thank you

Comment: Define "safely". Unless you have a backup of it from before the update, you can't go back 'downhill' without a complete wipe & start afresh. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Comment: Your disk is now APFS which El Capitan does not understand. I'm afraid you'll need to wipe the disk before installing El Capitan. Make a backup of your data first!